# FabricJS apply function only to certain types of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

How can you target certain types of object on the FabricJS canvas.

Such as iText objects only, shapes only or svg objects only.

If we take iText for example I don't mean target one that says 'Hello' and over one that says 'Goodbye' but **all** iText objects and **not** shape objects.

In the case of the demo below the mouse:down function should apply to iText and not the rectangle (baring in mind the rectangle may not always have a var rect).

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// Example function to apply to 1 type of object only
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
    if (e.target) {
        if (!e.target.__corner) {
            e.target.toggle('flipX');
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
        e.target.__corner = null;
    }
});

// create a rectangle
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  angle: 20,
  fill: 'red'
});
// set rectangle gradient
rect.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: -rect.width / 2,
    y1: 0,
    x2: rect.width / 2,
    y2: 0,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#ffe47b',
        1: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
    }
});
canvas.add(rect);

//create text
var text = new fabric.IText('Hello World!',{
   top:100,
   left:200,
   textBackgroundColor: '#000',
   fontSize:30,
   fill: 'white',
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   textAlign: 'center',
});
canvas.add(text);

canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
#canvas { background-color:#f4f4f4; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: have you figured it out? :)

Comment: @ℊααnd No, still giving it ago and yesterday's :D darshangs' answer below helps a little but not sure if it's a solution that works for me, it does in the demo though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To target certain types of object, you'd have to check the object type before flipping it horizontally.
These are some of the object types *`rect`, `i-text`, `path-group`* *etc.*

```js
/*** available object types ***/
/*
| Object |                Type                |
|--------|------------------------------------|
| Shape  | rect, circle, polygon and so on... |
| Text   | i-text                             |
| Image  | image                              |
| SVG    | path-group                         |
*/

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// mouse event
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
    if (e.target) {
        var objType = 'path-group';
        if (!e.target.__corner && e.target.type === objType) {
            e.target.toggle('flipX');
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
        e.target.__corner = null;
    }
});

// create a rectangle
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    angle: 20,
    fill: 'red'
});
// set rectangle gradient
rect.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: -rect.width / 2,
    y1: 0,
    x2: rect.width / 2,
    y2: 0,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#ffe47b',
        1: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
    }
});
canvas.add(rect);

//create text
var text = new fabric.IText('Hello World!', {
    top: 100,
    left: 200,
    textBackgroundColor: '#000',
    fontSize: 30,
    fill: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
});
canvas.add(text);

// add image
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg', function(img) {
    img.set({
        top: 150,
        left: 200
    })
    img.scaleToWidth(100);
    img.scaleToHeight(100);
    canvas.add(img);
});

// add svg
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('https://istack.000webhostapp.com/drop.svg', function(objects, options) {
    var svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    svg.set({
        top: 150,
        left: 40
    })
    canvas.add(svg);
});

canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Amazing :D thanks I was able to pin point most objects using the information you provided. There are a few illusive objects though that I can't find the values for. It's the animatedsprite's, I don't seem able to select those or normal text, as opposed to i-text, I tried just the 'text' object value but it didn't work and 'free drawings' :\ where do i find the values, I can't see a reference in the docs? Btw you are a FabricJS master.

Comment: ah. thanks :-) for *animated sprite*, *normal text* and *free drawings* use `sprite`, `text` *(works for me)* and `path` respectively

Answer (score 2):

Try using `e.target.type`.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// Example function to apply to 1 type of object only
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.type === "i-text") {
    if (!e.target.__corner) {
      e.target.toggle('flipX');
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
    e.target.__corner = null;
  }
});

// create a rectangle
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  angle: 20,
  fill: 'red'
});
// set rectangle gradient
rect.setGradient('fill', {
  type: 'linear',
  x1: -rect.width / 2,
  y1: 0,
  x2: rect.width / 2,
  y2: 0,
  colorStops: {
    0: '#ffe47b',
    1: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
  }
});
canvas.add(rect);

//create text
var text = new fabric.IText('Hello World!', {
  top: 100,
  left: 200,
  textBackgroundColor: '#000',
  fontSize: 30,
  fill: 'white',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  textAlign: 'center',
});
canvas.add(text);

canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Someone voted this down, but I found this solution worked for me. It was just that the selected answer gave more information and helped me further :)